# Float div side by side - Two column layout

Tags: html, floating

Is there a possibility for the div (#contentwrapper) to take all the remaining width while floating side by side for the next example:

```css
#maincontainer {
    width:1000px;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#leftcolumn {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height:20px;
    background: blue;
}
#contentwrapper {
    float:right;
    width:900px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
    <div id="contentwrapper"></div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/A5HM7/4/)

Comment: What do you mean with floating side by side?

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, please consider to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. If you feel you have answered your own question you can add your own answer and accept it..

Answer (score 1):

Try using flexbox. It is better than using tables. Make sure to include the vendor prefixes in it.

https://jsfiddle.net/qa6cds9c/

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
    <div id="contentwrapper"></div>
</div>

#maincontainer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
}

#leftcolumn {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100px;
}

#contentwrapper {
    border: 1px solid green;   
    height: 400px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: It would be good to add the prefixes in your answer. Perhaps also a link to supported browsers since it is not fully supported? If you add these I will plus one.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple. Using good ol' CSS:

- `float-left` only the **left** element
- add `margin-left` to the right column to compensate the left's one width:

```css
#leftcolumn {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
#contentwrapper {
    margin-left: 100px; /* same as #leftcolumn width */
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="leftcolumn">left</div>
    <div id="contentwrapper">right<br>contentwrapper</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here the contentwrapper is also behind the leftcolumn. This is a problem when you start adding content or changing heights.

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma ohh thanks! I forgot to add the left margin! ♪♫

Answer (score -1):

You could use a table instead of The divs. Or make the divs behave as a table using CSS.

When you have two table cells in a row and set the width for one then the other will fill the remaining space.

Not sure if this is considered best practice though.

Comment: That's a great idea though. Besides why would you consider this as a "bad" practice?

Comment: Maybe tables are passé. There's probably some CSS3 alternative out there already :p

Comment: Ah, well.. Solved the issue using the original table tag. Thanks for the idea though!